# PHP defines default values when the class have not __construct()?

Tags: php, constructor, default-constructor

```
<?php
class Alumn {
  private $name;
  private $mat;
  } 
  function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
  function getMat()
  {
    return $this->mat;
  }
}
 $a = new Alumn();
?>
```

In this case `$name` and `$mat` get zero value? If I use a echo `$a->getName()` in the last line I have not return. Anyone knows it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: They are set to `null`. You might aswell just test yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` and `$mat` get `null` values (they're not defined). You get nothing returned because there is nothing to return...they're `null`.

```
if($a->getName() == NULL)
    print "Alumn->name is NULL";
if($a->getMat() == NULL)
    print "Alumn->mat is NULL";
```

See the following for output:
http://ideone.com/lcuSNB